# JavaScript, destructuring vs assignation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, object-destructuring

I had this code:

```
const availableDays = status.availableDays;
```

And I had a suggestion to change with:

```
const { availableDays } = status;
```

They both are one line code, but I wonder if there is an explanation on why would be the destructuring a better way to code than the first one.

If the code would be:

```
const availableDays = status.availableDays;
const someVar = status.someVar;
const someOtherVar = status.someOtherVar;
```

I know that would be shortest (don't know if better) this way:

```
const { availableDays, someVar, someOtherVar } = status;
```

But my question goes to a performance, security, readability, etc reason.

Comment: It is certainly more readable. Security and performance should be identical.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage is in not repeating the identifier, which is the same for the property name and the variable.

This makes the code more concise, easier to read/understand, and reduces the potential for spelling mistakes. There is no difference to performance (if not counting code size) or security (if not counting bug likelihood).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the improved readability:

```
const myObj = { availableDays: 3, someVar: "foo", someOtherVar: "bar" };

function myFunc(status) {
   const availableDays = status.availableDays;
   const someVar = status.someVar;
   const someOtherVar = status.someOtherVar;

   // do stuff
}
```

Can be refactored to:

```
function myFunc({ availableDays, someVar, someOtherVar }) {
   // do stuff
}
```

This is especially useful when dealing with prop passing into React components.